# The characteristic polynomial of an ODE is equal to the characteristic polynomial of the companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

One can write a homogeneous linear differential equation with real constant coefficients $a_k \in \mathbb R$ of degree $n \in \mathbb N$
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
    0 = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} a_{k} \cdot u^{(k)}(t)
    \qquad \text{with } a_n = 1
\end{equation}
as a system of $n$ differential equations like so:
\begin{align*}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 u \\ \vdots \\ u^{(n - 1)}
 \end{pmatrix}'
  + \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & - 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & - 1 & 0 &  0 \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
  0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & -1 \\
  a_0 & a_1 & \ldots & \ldots & a_{n - 1}
  \end{pmatrix}}_{:= A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  u \\ \vdots \\ u^{(n - 1)}
  \end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
The characteristic polynomial of $(1)$ is defined to be $\chi(\lambda) := \sum_{k = 0}^{n} a_{k} \cdot \lambda^{k}$ with $a_n = 1$.
I want to show that the characterisitic polynomial of $A$, $\det(\lambda I - A)$, is equal to the characterisitic polynomial of the differential equation.

Here's is what I tried to prove it. If $A = \begin{pmatrix} B & C \\ D & E \end{pmatrix}$ is a block matrix where $E$ is a scalar and thus $C$ and $D$ are vectors, we have $\det(A) = (E - D B^{-1} C) \det(B)$, if $B$ is invertible.

Defining $$B := \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & -1 & \ddots & \vdots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\ 0 & \ldots & 0 & \lambda & - 1 \\ 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{(n - 1) \times (n - 1)}, \qquad
C := \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ - 1 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{n - 1}, \qquad D :=\begin{pmatrix} a_0 & a_1 & \ldots & a_{n - 3} & a_{n - 2} \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{1, n - 1}$$
I obtain for $\lambda \ne 0$ (as $\det(B) = \lambda^{n - 1}$)
\begin{align*}
\det(\lambda I - A)
& = \det\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1 & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\
a_0 & a_1 & \ldots & a_{n - 2} & a_{n - 1} + \lambda
\end{pmatrix} \\
& = \lambda^{n - 1} \left[ (a_{n - 1} + \lambda) - \begin{pmatrix} a_0& \ldots & a_{n - 2} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \lambda^{-1} & \lambda^{-2} & \ldots & \lambda^{-(n - 1)} \\ 0 & \lambda^{-1} & \ddots &  \vdots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \ldots & 0 & \lambda^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ - 1 \end{pmatrix} \right] \\
& = \lambda^{n - 1} \left[ (a_{n - 1} + \lambda) + \begin{pmatrix} a_0& \ldots & a_{n - 2} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\lambda^{-(n - 1)} \\ \vdots \\  \lambda^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \right] \\
& = \lambda^{n} + a_{n - 1} \lambda^{n - 1} + \begin{pmatrix} a_0 & \ldots & a_{n - 2} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\  \lambda^{n-2} \end{pmatrix} \\
& = \lambda^{n} + a_{n - 1} \lambda^{n - 1} + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 2} a_k \lambda^k. 
\end{align*}
**Edit** I miscalculated $B^{-1}$, so now the calculation works. Is there a simpler way to show this result?

Comment: I'd rather say it looks like the transpose of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of a polynomial.

Comment: I haven't checked carefully, but I think you can directly show that any eigenvalue of $A$ must also be a root of the characteristic polynomial of (1), and perhaps vice versa. (Just look at what $Ax = \lambda x$ tells us about the components of $x$.) That seems potentially helpful.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, I didn't know a proper name, and now switched your proposed terminology.

Comment: note that your $A$ is not the Companion matrix, but the negative of the Companion matrix.  Transposition conventions vary but don't affect the char poly... negation *does* though.  This could lead to sign errors / discrepancies.

Comment: Use induction on $n$; it is trivial to expand $\det (\lambda I-A)$ along the top row and get what you need. See any treatment of rational canonical form.